# Unity Multiplayer attempts

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I'm trying to follow the Official Unity tutorial 
[Multiplayer Networking](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/handling-non-player-objects?playlist=29690). up to this tutorial, everything seems smooth though.

however, now when I run it in the editor it seems fine, but on the builder non of the enemies appear, or is even created.

any ideas why there is a difference between the host on the editor and the host after the build?

thanks

The code:

```
using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class EnemySpawner : NetworkBehaviour
{

public GameObject enemyPrefab;
public int numberOfEnemies;

public override void OnStartServer()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEnemies; i++)
    {
        var spawnPosition = new Vector3(
            Random.Range(-5.0f, 5.0f),
            0.0f,
            Random.Range(-5.0f, 5.0f));

        var spawnRotation = Quaternion.Euler(
            0.0f,
            Random.Range(0, 180),
            0.0f);

        var enemy = (GameObject)Instantiate(enemyPrefab, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
        NetworkServer.Spawn(enemy);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you share some of your code for spawning enemies?

Comment: I've put the code, it is just like the one they have used

Comment: Do you get any Error Output? Is the enemy prefab added to the prefab setting in the NetworkManager?

Comment: Is enemyPrefab spelt ok?

Comment: it was added to the NetworkManager, and I have no errors at all.
When the I run it in the editor the enemies spawn alright, but the build just cant see them.
If I run the build as the host, the editor shows the enemies werent even created.